# Vue-Chartjs onComplete custom labels - prevent blinking

Tags: label, chart.js, data-visualization, vue-chartjs

To calculate custom labels for Vue-Chartjs the only solution I could find was via

```
animation: { onComplete: function () {
```

The problem that follows is that these labels are blinking on bar hover. I also saw the same behaviour in many other custom label examples/solutiond. Did anyone manage to solve this?

See example here [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ds8r2apg/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blinking effect is caused because the animation is only triggered when the bars are hovered. You can use the `onHover` option to trigger whenever the chart canvas is hovered.

Here's an example logic: 
(uses the plugin chartjs-plugin-datalabels to make it easier)

```
options : {
 onHover : function (e) {
    const display = e.type === 'mouseout' ? false : true
    const labels = this.chart.options.plugins.datalabels
    if (display&&labels.display) return //avoid updating if already set
    labels.display = display
    this.chart.update();
 }
}
```

[working example](https://jsfiddle.net/ellisdod/6xt1a4ru/)

Comment: in your solution the labels still blink. but the plugin _chartjs-plugin-datalabels_ enables you to set `datalabels: {  display: true}`

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise you wanted the data labels to be there permanently.